# Exclude folders from "Photos & Videos" in Amazon Cloud Drive?

Tags: photos, cloud-storage, amazon-cloud-drive

I have unlimited Amazon Cloud Drive & unlimited photos.

When I browse "[Photos & Videos](https://www.amazon.com/gp/photos/list)" on web/mobile, I see ALL photos & videos in my drive, regardless of which folder they are in.

This is annoying. I would like to ONLY see photos/videos that are within the "Pictures" folder (where photos are auto-uploaded from my devices).

Is this possible? Exclude other folders from appearing in "Photos & Videos" ?

Answer (score 2):

This came in from Amazon:

> Hello,
>
> At this time, we do not have an option to exclude other folders
>   appearing in Photos & Videos section of the Cloud Drive website. I
>   understand, this do not sound comfortable. I'm sorry, but please note
>   our development team are working on various improvement, to make Cloud
>   drive feature more user friendly.
>
> I’ve passed your comments to our Cloud Drive team for consideration.
>
> Customer feedback like yours helps us continue to improve our products
>   and provide better service to our customers.
>
> Thanks for your understanding. We look forward to seeing you again
>   soon.
>
> We'd appreciate your feedback. Please use the links below to tell us
>   about your experience today.
>
> Best regards, Aneesh

Comment: this functionality will be really helpful